# .htaccess .Redirecting Except a Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mobile

i have a domain named **example.com** and a subdomain for mobile version **m.example.com**
and **another subdomain. xxx.exmaple.com which i dont want to redirect**
using .htaccess when i redirect **example.com** to **m.example.com,** it is also redirecting **xxx.example.com** to **m.example.com**

i have following code

```
# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
  RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
 RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

 # cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
  RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

 # Check if this looks like a mobile device
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera   
       mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

  # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
 # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
 RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this condition below in place of: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$
```

Your last rule would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$
# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R,L]
```